# How to give the action call in form a specific product.id?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

I have a problem. In my template.xml I have a form tag with an action:

```
<form action="/my/test/#{product.id}" method="post">
```

How can I give the action call a specific product.id. I mean when it's product.id "1" it should call /my/test/1 ,when it's product.id "2" = /my/test/2

How can I handle this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand what you do.

In odoo if you would like to create a dynamic attribute for tag. you have 2 possibilities:

#### t-att-$name

$name is the name of your attribute.

example

```
<t t-set="class" t-value="['class1','class2]"/>
<span t-att-class="class[0]"/>
```

the html code return will be

```
<span class="class1"/>
```

the t-att-$name it used to evaluated the code.

#### t-attf-$name

same as previous, but the parameter is a format string instead of just an expression, often useful to mix literal and non-literal string:

example

```
<t t-set="class" t-value="['class1','class2]"/>
<span t-attf-class="mainclass #{class[0]}"/>
<span t-attf-class="mainclass #{class[1]}"/>
```

the html code return will be

```
<span class="mainclass class1"/>
<span class="mainclass class2"/>
```

In your case, you need concatenating literal value with a variable.

You must used t-attf-$name

```
<form t-attf-action="/my/test/#{product.id}" method="post">
```

Now in the python code, you need to create a dynamic route.

in your case, you route must be like this.

```
@http.route(['/my/test/<int:product_id>/'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
def my_test_product(self, product_id, **kwargs):
    #your code
    return request.website.render("your_model.template_id")
```

Comment: thank you so much ,this helped me alot, I fixed it with this:
<form t-attf-action="/my/test/#{product.id}" method="post">

Comment: You can find the lot of informations in this documentation about Qweb https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html